# PostgreSql Merge Statement Deletions

Tags: sql, postgresql

A `MERGE` statement is slated for release in postgresql-15.  I have installed v15 and have tested a basic `upsert`, but I cannot see how a `when not matched by source then delete` (mssql syntax) would be handled.

The postgres syntax is defined [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html)

Comment: You should refer  to the [official manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) for the complete syntax, not to some emails that were exchanged during the 8.4 development (which never was implemented). But yes, the `not matched by source` was not implemented. As far as I know, the implementation in 15 follows the specification of the SQL standard. So if there is no `then delete` then either it's not specified in the SQL standard or there simply wasn't enough time to do it.

Comment: good spot - I will update the link

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I believe it is not specified in the Sql standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletions will not be supported in postgresl-15

Answer (score 0):

The `MERGE` statement as released in PostgreSQL 15 did end up supporting `THEN DELETE`, but it does not support `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` as you have observed. It only supports the standard `WHEN NOT MATCHED`, which means that row exists in the source and not in the target.

There is [a patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAEZATCWqnKGc57Y_JanUBHQXNKcXd7r%3D0R4NEZUVwP%2BsyRkWbA%40mail.gmail.com) in the works that was last updated in July 2023 that would add support for `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, so hopefully we can have this feature in a future release.

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html

> MERGE actions have the same effect as regular UPDATE, INSERT, or
> DELETE commands of the same names. The syntax of those commands is
> different, notably that there is no WHERE clause and no table name is
> specified. **All actions refer to the target_table_name**, though
> modifications to other tables may be made using triggers.

both MSSQL and PostgreSQL can only do merge_not_matched then insert operation/do nothing.

**All actions refer to target_table_name.** `when not matched by source then delete` is like delete operation where condition is always false. So there is no effect. Then if it not implemented then that make sense.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point.  I regularly write merges in mssql that are capable of syncing a target table from a source, including deletions of missing records.  The lack of a WHERE clause refers to the synatx of the INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE actions.

Comment: `when not matched by source then delete`   if you are refer to ` when not matched by source then delete target  table` then all target table record will be deleted. If you are refer to `when not matched by source then delete source table`  then like I said all action refer to target table. so when not matched, the target table can only do is insert the not matched or do nothing. @HughJones

Comment: have a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03fbe7 and then do a SELECT * FROM TABLE1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c0504c411d05c2552455792eebbb7fbc @HughJones the best I can get. dbfidle15 beta not working. You need use in your own machine.

Comment: @HughJones I wonder in MSSQL, how you can delete target table (3, 'Record To Be Deleted');

Comment: @HughJones see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=fc5cfb03e05a0e5a1117a249f81e8355

Comment: `I wonder in MSSQL, how you can delete target table` That is precisely my question - in mssql it is supported, in postgres it appears not be. `MERGE Table1
USING Table2 src
   ON Field1_1 = src.Field2_1
   
WHEN MATCHED AND Field1_2 <> src.Field2_2 THEN UPDATE
  SET Field1_2 = src.Field2_2
  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(Field1_1, Field1_2)
VALUES(src.Field2_1, src.Field2_2)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;`

Comment: @HughJones You are right. I reread again about MSSQL. They have when not matched by source and when not matched by target. In postgresql, I think you can just use delete and join.